# AWS Load Balancer does not forward Cookies

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, load-balancing, sticky-sessions

I have an AWS "Classic Load Balancer" that relays the traffic and for 3 EC2 instances. On these EC2 instances (it's simple Linux machines) I have a GlassFish 4.1 running and listening to port 80.

When calling the URL for a single server, everything is fine (works as it is supposed to) but when the traffic is relayed by the Load Balancer, the request to the application server has no cookies.

I checked the balancer's *"Enable load balancer generated cookie stickiness"* option and also tried *"Enable application generated cookie stickiness"*.
Both times the balancer chooses a target server for the first request and uses relays all subsequent requests to the same server - but omits the cookies.

**For example**
After the login I have these cookies:

```
AWSELB      DD17B9....
JSESSIONID  8f22ce....
mnzkks      1869:1000:34....
```

When I click on any link on the page, I see that my browser includes the new cookies in the request:

```
GET /mypage/detail HTTP/1.1
Host: my.page.com
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 OPR/45.0.2552.888
Referer: https://my.page.com/dashboard
Cookie: JSESSIONID=8f22ce ...;
        AWSELB= DD17B9....; 
        mnzkks=1869:1000:345..
```

In a filter of my application I print out all the cookie names and check for the "mnzkks". If I can't find any cookie it prints `no cookie` :)

When using the server's original URL it prints

```
AWSELB
JSESSIONID
mnzkks
```

When using the URL of the balancer it always prints `no cookie`, even though the browser includes all 3 cookies in the request

**who ate my cookies?**

Comment: I did a bit of searching to see if I could help answer this, but I can't find any documentation. Since no-one here can answer perhaps you should try the AWS forums? If you work it out please answer your own question, it's interesting and could help others.

Comment: Does your `Set-Cookie` response have a trailing semicolon?  If so, [these AWS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-sticky-sessions.html) suggest that that may be one of the issues: "If you have a trailing semicolon in the Set-Cookie field of an application cookie, the load balancer ignores the cookie."

Comment: After all this time, I wonder if and how you solved this issue, because I am having the exact same problem.

Comment: I am sorry, but I never found out what the problem was. I tried copying the configurations of a similar setup but it still didn't work so I had to change my strategy and setup a REST environment (using AWS lambdas) where I didn't rely on cookies. But I sure hope you will find a solution and maybe share it here?